# v1 deg out = zero?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

### My Attempt

Yes it is true. There is one directed edge between two vertices and you can see that there is one vertex that the out-degree is zero. If you want to fix that, you can add a vertex and a directed edge between the new and old vertex that have out-degree zero. But if you keep repeating this, you running into the same problem.

The other option is to connect the vertex with outdegree zero to an existing vertex. But if you do that then u can create a directed cycle.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose all vertices have outdegree greater than zero. Let $v_{1}$
be an arbitrary vertex. By the assumption, it follows that we can
find $v_{2}$ such that $v_{1}\rightarrow v_{2}$. Continue this process
to obtain a path of the form $v_{1}\rightarrow v_{2}\rightarrow\cdots$.
Since the number of vertices are finite, it follows by the pigeon
hole principle that $v_{i}=v_{j}$ for some $i\neq j$, and hence
we have a cycle.